# Check occurrence of word appearing in datatable column

Tags: c#, system.data.datatable

I have the data below in a datatable this is example data. I would like get the occurrence of 12,13 in the datatable as normally there would be 10-20 million row in the datatable.

```
Customer  |  quantity  |  Product  | Code 

1         |  3         |  Product  | 12 
2         |  4         |  Product  | 13 
3         |  1         |  Product  | 12 
4         |  6         |  Product  | 13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about simple `for each loop`

```
private int getCount(int yourSearchDigit)
{
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in youDataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Code"]) == yourSearchDigit)
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable`:

```
int[] allowedCodes = new []{ 12, 13 };
var rows = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r => allowedCodes.Contains(r.Field<int>("Code")));
```

However, if you have 10-20 million row in the datatable you should consider to do the filtering in the database itself.

If you want to know the number they occur:

```
int count = table.AsEnumerable()
                 .Count(r => allowedCodes.Contains(r.Field<int>("Code")));
```

Comment: so would this count the number of time is has occurred.

Comment: @JimBrad if you did a .Count() on it yes.

Comment: @JimBrad: Edited my answer to show how to count the rows without selecting anything else. You can also add the `Count` without predicate after the `Where` as Thomas has mentioned.

Comment: @JimBrad: I've showed it already in my answer (the last query). You could also use the first query: `int count = rows.Count();`.